# how to select current date in "Javascript event calendar" (FullCalendar)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

For reference use this link "https://fullcalendar.io/"

Answer (score 0):

```
var todaysDate = driver.findelement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'fc-today')]").getAttribute("data-date");
```